# How to Remove the line using regular expression in dreamviewer

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++, dreamweaver

```
lnk+='<li><a title="Damages form (Unit)" >

lnk+='<li><a title="ant text here" >
```

Above codes have to remove using regular expression in dreamviewer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove these lines, you can use this RegExp:

```
var regex = /lnk\+='<li><a.*>/
```

It will select all lines starting with `lnk+='<li><a` and end at the last `>` of these lines

Then you can do :

```
theStringContainingTheseLines.replace(regex, '');
```

To replace these lines with *'nothing'*

Your question was not very clear so, i don't know if it is exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there a FIND/REPLACE option in Dreamweaver ? You can find : "lnk+='<li><a" and replace : ' '